# how to get started in writing this Orchard module

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I'm a newbie in Orchard development, and I'm now about to write my first module for it.
my requirements will contain a multi-page path in order for the user to complete the order.

1- search for your desired number

2- search results (pick your number).

3- enter your info

4- thank you (log this order)

**I don't want someone to do my work**, but I need to know where to start, and how to manage my assets, and the most important, is how will I be able to manage the user interaction wit my form.

many many thanks, hope to hear from you.

**Update:** This has not been finalized yet, as all of the resources I've checked couldn't answer my question.
what I need to achieve here is something like a wizard. some steps depending on user inputs. but all the samples was a one-page module with administration page or something.
 please help.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: well, I've started by watching some videos but I don't know how structure my module well enough for Orchard, also I don't know how to handle responses from my form and display the appropriate step, as well as saving this step into the data store.

Comment: see this http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1

Comment: @MohammedElSayed Have you tried looking at some other modules to see how they work? How about looking at some of Orchard's core modules? There are an abundance of third party modules available from the Orchard gallery, and a few that do ecommerce.

Comment: @mdm: thanks for the comment, I've installed the source code and took a look on some of the built-in modules, but I've found many parts that need to be there in order for the modules to work (driver, migration, handler, etc) so I've asked this question so I may find someone who has the experience to let me know where and how to start, and the basic building steps that I should follow in order to complete the requirements.

Comment: Ok, well you are on the right track. I suggest the next thing you need to do is thoroughly read the tutorial that Andres linked to above (it's a fantastic tutorial and the writer is actually speaking at next month's Orchard conference, so he knows what he is talking about ;) That should help clarify a lot of the questions you have about what components you need to develop - and I'm sure it will help that it is also oriented at an ecommerce solution. If you work through this and still have questions, you will be better placed to ask targeted questions and get better answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best explanation for building a module that I have seen is on www.Pluralsight.com.  The content is not free but depending on your situation it may be worth the cost.

[Advanced Orchard](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=adv-orchard&highlight=kevin-kuebler_adv-orchard-m4-non-content-data-and-mvc%2a6!kevin-kuebler_adv-orchard-m1-getting-started%2a1,5,6,7,3,4!kevin-kuebler_adv-orchard-m6-finishing-touches%2a13,14!kevin-kuebler_adv-orchard-m2-creating-a-module!kevin-kuebler_adv-orchard-m3-creating-a-custom-content-part#adv-orchard-m4-non-content-data-and-mvc) by Kevin Kuebler

[Orchard Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=orchard-fundamentals&highlight=kevin-kuebler_introduction-to-orchard%2a1,2!kevin-kuebler_shape-of-orchard!kevin-kuebler_modules-and-content%2a1,8,4!kevin-kuebler_themes-and-widgets%2a9!kevin-kuebler_blogs-and-users#introduction-to-orchard) by Kevin Kuebler

Comment: I have watched those videos and they are a little out of date with the latest version of Orchard, but as a starting point they are excellent. If you are a half decent developer these videos will definitely send you along your way nicely for the cost of a book or two; plus videos on other topics which are actually fantastic.